# New Instance of Service is getting created every time when opening any Component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular15

Am getting new instance of service every time opening any component.

As per Angular documentation if any service component is having below code at top then it will act as singleton.

```
    @Injectable({
     providedIn: "root"
    })
```

But constructor of service is getting called in every other component.

Kindly Check the code as below:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {BehaviorSubject, Subject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
      providedIn: "root"
})
export class SharedService {

      constructor(private _router: Router) {
        console.log(Math.random())
      }
}
```

Components in which am using this service are as below:

First Component

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from "../../../services/SharedService";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-freelancer-job-item',
  templateUrl: './freelancer-job-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./freelancer-job-item.component.scss']
})
export class FreelancerJobItemComponent {

    constructor( private sharedService: SharedService ) {}

}
```

Second Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from "../../services/SharedService";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-job-detail',
  templateUrl: './job-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./job-detail.component.scss']
})
export class JobDetailComponent {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

}
```

Console log of shared service printed random number when first component having service as constructor got called.
but same console log was printed again when Second component got called.

I have not added service in appModule's providers:
Needed code in AppModule is as below

```
{
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
}
```

Angular version Used : 15

Version Command response is as below:

> @angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.2
>
> @angular-devkit/core            15.2.2
>
> @angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.2
>
> @angular/cdk                    15.2.4
>
> @angular/fire                   7.6.1
>
> @angular/material               15.2.4
>
> @schematics/angular             15.2.2
>
> rxjs                            7.8.0
>
> typescript                      4.9.5

I have checked every answers on stack overflow, but have not gotten the solution that workd.

Comment: Can you provide a StackBlitz reproducing your issue? I have just pasted your snippets into StackBlitz to test myself and I correctly only see one `console.log()` being called https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qtosvf